How to group by two different rows in to one matching result
I have to write a query to form a Bar chart. In the bar chart x axis should be grouped based on datetime (dateValue) and y axis should have sum of numbers(stringValue). Both these two fields are custom fields in my task_project_field table which has two entries for this values. How to achieve a result where i can group based on datetime and sum the number
Here is my query:
fiddle

Please post a clear sample input table with expected output.

@TimBiegeleisen I have edited the question as per you request. Please watch out my query. query produce the above table and I want to further group based on month column and sum the stringValue columns, Both these columns are in two different row but shares same id(task_id)

I don't undertstand your expected results. You just want two values returned? I would expect that the desired results from a sql statement would be a table. At this point it's not clear what you are wanting as output. Please post sample data and desired results. Sample data would be one or more tables, and desired results would also be a table. I suspect all you want to do is use a GROUP BY with some max() and sum() thrown into the SELECT, but I'm totally guessing.

@JNevill I have added the screenshot of my table and expected desire result as well Please go thru and ping if more info needed

In the future, please avoid screenshots of code, text, and table results. You can use stackoverflow's markdown for tables. Websites like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ can help format tabular data into markdown or ascii with the push of a button. This way we can replicate in dbfiddle or our local envirnments quicky without having to transcribe from a picture, which most folks aren't going to take the time to do.

@JNevill Thanks for the help. I tried the approach you suggested. It did not work as expected. Im writing the code the dbfiddle now. Give me some time i will write all sql scripts and share the link in comments

Your help much appreciated @JNevill As per your request I have added all codes here in fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/fWs6FQpf

Backwards engineering your tables from the SQL you shared, it seems like you have an EAV design. In essence you have multiple key/value stored in your task_project_field table for each task_id. In this case field_id/string/date_value.
The best way to deal with this is to LEFT OUTER JOIN to your task_project_field table for each field_id you are wanting to grab. Otherwise you end up needing to aggregate and things are going to get ugly.
Consider:
SELECT t.id,
  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(tpf349.dateValue), '-', year(tpf349.dateValue)) as displayKey,
  tpf371.stringValue as countsum
FROM task as t
  inner join task_membership tm on t.id = tm.task_id
    and tm.deleted_at = 0
    and t.deleted_at = 0
  left join task_project_field as tpf371 on t.id = tpf371.task_id
    and tpf371.deleted_at = 0
    and tpf371.field_id = 371
  left join task_project_field as tpf349 on t.id = tpf349.task_id
    and tpf349.deleted_at = 0
    and tpf349.field_id = 349

Here we join twice to tpf; aliasing it according to the field_id we are interested in. We also include a new condition in the join criteria to specify which field_id we want for this particular join.
+---------+------------+----------+
|   id    | displayKey | countsum |
+---------+------------+----------+
| 2981641 | April-2024 |      900 |
| 2981642 | June-2024  |   123456 |
| 2981643 | May-2024   |     8900 |
| 2981644 | June-2024  |       90 |
| 2981645 | May-2024   |       16 |
+---------+------------+----------+

This output is based on the initial screenshot "output" you shared.
You can see this in action at this dbfiddle.
I also have a suspicion that your actual data is more complex and has more edge cases than this. It may be that some form of aggregation is necessary, but given the sample data you've shared, it's merely a hunch. For future question, please share sample data from each table and desired results made up from that sample data. The dbfiddle tool I linked to is a nice step up from that as folks that are interested in helping you can immediately go and write sql against your sample data.

I have added the sample data here https://dbfiddle.uk/fWs6FQpf

I got the query as expected. I just messed up the tpf371 and tpf349 while grouping. I should use tpf349 in group_by instead of tpf371. Updated the same in https://dbfiddle.uk/XfhZ9Pln Again thank you for you time and patients.

Nice! Those complexities are about what I was suspecting. So glad you figured it out!
